# Is max-plus semiring isomorphic to $\mathbb{R_{+}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semiring, ring-isomorphism

Define two new binary operation $\oplus,\otimes$ on $\mathbb{R_{+}}$(positive real number),$$a\oplus b=max(a,b),\\a\otimes b=a+b,$$
It is easy to see $(\mathbb{R_{+}},\oplus,\otimes)$ is a semiring.I want to know if it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R_{+}},+,.)$

I tried using the deformation of $log_{q}x$ to construct the isomorphism.But it doesn't work.

Comment: Solve the equation $x\oplus x=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, otherwise we don't even have additive identity. $0$ is an identity for both $\oplus$ and $\otimes$. This implies that $(\mathbb{R}_+,\oplus,\otimes)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}_+,+,.)$ since $1 \neq 0$ in $(\mathbb{R}_+,+,.)$.

Comment: Alright if it doesn't have additive identity $0$ at all then they are not isomorphic since $(\mathbb{R}_+,+,.)$ has both additive and multiplicative identity. So either way the conclusion is the same.